# Prevent double click React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Hello everyone im trying to prevent double click but im not doing any API calls, and dont want to use timeout

I did few approachs

first one

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
const App = () => {
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < 99999999999; i++) {}
      resolve(false);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        disabled={disabled}
        onClick={() => {
          setDisabled(true);
          handleClick().then((res) => {
            setDisabled(res);
          });
        }}
      >
        {disabled ? "Disabled" : "Enable"}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

this approach didnt change my button to disabled and it blocked my main thread so its bad.

Second and third approachs are look like same but its not

I know click event order is (onMouseDown -> onMouseUp -> onClick) so i tried to put my setDisabled to both onMouseDown and onMouseUp

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
const App = () => {
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < 9999; i++) {}
      resolve(false);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        disabled={disabled}
        onClick={() => {
          console.log("onClick");
          handleClick().then((res) => {
            setDisabled(res);
          });
        }}
        onMouseDown={() => {
          console.log("mouseDown");
          setDisabled(true);
        }}
      >
        {disabled ? "Disabled" : "Enable"}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

But since my button is disabled onClick event not fired.

I can use debounce/setTimeout etc. but i dont want to use any hard-coded timeout values.

Is there any other way to make this?

To sum up;

I want my button disabled until my long for loop is finished after that again my button is enable

Comment: First of all, what's with the for loops?
Second, you know that you can use useRef here, right?

Comment: for loop is not a real scenario its just a long proccess @DBS

Comment: @SergeySosunov i want my button clickable again after my long proccess finish

Comment: would you get this issue of hardcoding when u apply a real scenario. for example in a fetch call you can re-enable the button once the data arrives?

Comment: @Dimitar i dont know if you know you can post your answer, If you want you cant edit codesandbox -> https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-lamport-9kn7gs?file=/src/App.js

Comment: thank you @SergeySosunov i just wrapped for loop with setTimeout 0 maybe after some time ill use web worker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @SergeySosunov

The button was not changing to a disabled state because the UI thread was blocked by a CPU-intensive operation fired just after setDisabled call itself. This blocking prevents React from re-rendering with the new state. To resolve this, a timeout before the CPU operation was added, allowing React and the UI to have some time for re-rendering.

```js
const App = () => {
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setDisabled(true);

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        for (let i = 0; i < 9999999999; i++) {}
        resolve(false);
      }, 0);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        disabled={disabled}
        onClick={() => {
          handleClick().then((res) => {
            setDisabled(res);
          });
        }}
      >
        {disabled ? "Disabled" : "Enable"}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could keep a state of `{ lastClick: number, disabled: boolean }`, only toggling `disabled` if the current click time exceeds last click by X seconds -

```js
function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    lastClick: 0,
    disabled: false,
  })
  return <button
    children={state.disabled ? "disabled" : "enabled"}
    onClick={e => {
      const now = Date.now()
      setState({
        lastClick: now,
        disabled: (now - state.lastClick > 1000) // 1000 ms threshold
          ? !state.disabled
          : state.disabled
      })
    }}
    type="button"
  />
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app")).render(<App />)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Of course it's a burden to tangle that logic with your component however. I would recommend a higher-order event handler like `usePreventDoubleClick` -

```js
function usePreventDoubleClick(handler, timeout = 1000) {
  const last = React.useRef(Date.now())
  return {
    onClick: e => {
      const now = Date.now()
      if ((now - last.current) > timeout) {
        last.current = now
        handler(e)
      }
    }
  }
}   

function App() {
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = React.useState(false)
  return <button
    type="button"
    children={disabled ? "disabled" : "enabled"}
    {...usePreventDoubleClick(e => setDisabled(d => !d))}
  />
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app")).render(<App />)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: this is mad , neat

Comment: Thanks :) I updated the answer with a higher-order event handler example

Answer (score 0):

Why do not You use  backdropLoaders:-

You can create a React Mui Backdrop loader  and when you once click on the button just set backdrop state to true and after your long press set it to the false state

Comment: Well maybe because the state change will not be reflected due to UI will be completely frozen due to CPU-intensive operation?